# How can I modify this Assembly code in Navilnux?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, arm

Hello guys nice 2 meet you 
It is my first time to ask something
and
I not a good English speaker understand

I got a homework from my class

This code is from [Navilnux](https://github.com/kimeuichan/navilnux) `Entry.S` file.
If I want to make more short code than the original code, what should I do?

- `bl swiHandler` => I must not use that code

=========================================

```
.global navilnux_swiHandler
navilnux_swiHandler:
   stmfd sp!,{r0-r12,r14}
   mrs r1,spsr
   stmfd sp!,{r1}
   ldr r10,[lr,#-4]
   bic r10,r10,#Oxff000000
   mov r0,r10
   bl swiHandler
   ldmfd sp!,{r1}
   msr spsr_cxsf,r1
   ldmfd sp!,{r0-r12, pc}^
```

======================================

Comment: So you want to call a different function?  Or you want to inline it?  What do you want the code to do, then?

Comment: Both Just I need the shortest code

Comment: Ok, then just remove the line.  The function now does something different, but it's shorter.  Heck, remove all the lines. except the first and last.  Or remove them too and return with just `bx lr`.

Comment: This is what you recommend for me right??

   stmfd sp!,{r0-r12,r14}
   ldmfd sp!,{r0-r12, pc}^

Comment: and in ARM, Does it exit "return"??? sorry I am a beginner

Comment: Popping the saved LR (return address) into PC returns from the function.

Comment: I understood now . Thanks you so much ! god bless you!

Comment: that is the simplest swi exception code  right?

Comment: Yes, a function that returns without doing anything is the simplest thing possible.

Comment: If I call a function?,  Actually I didn't understand  if I call the function. just put "bx lr" ?